# PostGIS: problem with point count result when they are over the polygon edge

Tags: postgis, st-intersects, within

I have a PostgreSQL 12 database with PostGIS (using EPSG 4326). There are some tables with millions of points, and others with polygons.

In general , I had no problems with the queries. However, I recently noticed that in some cases, when I count points in polygons, some points are excluded or counted twice.
I use different tables with a grid of square polygons of distinct sizes, one degree, half degree, etc.
If I use:

```
SELECT polygon, count(point) 
FROM   point, polygon 
WHERE  ST_Within(point, polygon)
GROUP  BY 1
```

Some points located over the edge of the polygon are excluded from the count.

If I use:

```
SELECT polygon, count(point) 
FROM   point, polygon 
WHERE  ST_Intersects(point, polygon)
GROUP  BY 1
```

Those points get counted twice, once for each polygon.

How can I handle this situation to avoid errors in the analysis?

Answer (score 5):

The spatial predicate `ST_Contains` and the reverse `ST_Within` have the idiosyncrasy that "polygons do not contain their boundary" (see [this writeup](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2007/06/subtleties-of-ogc-covers-spatial.html)).
This is why your use of `ST_Within` does not report points lying on the boundary of polygons.

If a point lies on the boundary of two or more polygons then `ST_Intersects` will correctly detect that.  You will have to use some strategy to assign the point to a unique polygon (perhaps by choosing the polygon with lowest id value, if that is appropriate to your data model).

Comment: Yes, I've learned about that behavior when I detected the problem. However, it is neither clear nor easy to apply an assignation strategy. The basic data I have are point positions for vessels, and I usually use different groups of polygons for grouping. Some are grids of rectangles and others are very complex areas (eg. Exclusive Economic Zones, Marine Protected Areas, etc.)

Comment: I think this is a general SQL problem, not unique to spatial.  If there is no clear assignment strategy then perhaps it's fine to simply pick one containing polygon at random?  A query using `DISTINCT ON point` is one way to do this.